# How to convert from string to array?

Tags: julia

If `s = "1 2 3 4 5"`, how could we obtain an Integer Array from this. I would like to return a 5 element `Array{Int64,1}` `[1; 2; 3; 4; 5]`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As @isebarn used, `split(s)` is useful for splitting a string up into words (splitting by default at spaces):

```
julia> s = "1 2 3 4 5"
"1 2 3 4 5"

julia> split(s)
5-element Array{SubString{String},1}:
 "1"
 "2"
 "3"
 "4"
 "5"
```

Now you can use an array comprehension:

```
[parse(Int, ss) for ss in split(s)]
```

Here, `parse(Int, ss)` parses a string `ss` into an integer.

Note also that this returns a one-dimensional vector, not a two-dimensional array. There is no reason to prefer a two-dimensional array here -- this is a naturally one-dimensional object.

Comment: I agree that it is natural to expect a one-dimensional array and there is no reason I need the two-dimensional one. I will edit my question, thanks for the answer.

Comment: Also how about including the 0.5 feature (answer by @DNF)?

Answer (score 15):

If you are using version 0.5 or later, you can also do this:

```
int_s = parse.(split(s))
```

The trailing dot is the new compact broadcast notation. Possibly, this will be the preferred syntax in future versions.

Answer (score 6):

```
int_s = map(x -> parse(x), split(s))
```

**edit**

or as @David P. Sanders suggests, which I agree with

```
int_s = map(parse, split(s))
```

I've left out the Int part as I dont know if you plan of having only integers in your string

Comment: Note that you can (and should) write this as `map(parse, split(s))`

Comment: You are creating a new function that wraps the old one and does exactly the same thing. I do not think that this will be optimised away (although it might), so this will be a bit slower. Also it makes it look like something more complicated is going on, whereas actually you're just `map`ping `parse`. You could e.g. rewrite my answer as `map(x->parse(Int,x), split(s))`; here you do need to define the anonymous function, since you can't directly map the `parse(Int,x)` function due to the fact that it has two arguments, rather than one. I still find the array comprehension easier to follow though