# How to convert string to array with no spaces

Tags: arrays, string, julia

Related:

> [How to convert from string to array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39572884/how-to-convert-from-string-to-array)

This is a follow-up question. How would I make a list of all the digits in this number (currently as a string)?

```
"123" -> [1,2,3]
```

There are no delimiters here so how should I go about doing this?

Note as of now I am using the latest version of Julia, [v1.8.3](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/) so `parse` doesn't seem to work in the other question's answers. Error when I use `parse()`:

```
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching parse(::SubString{String})
Closest candidates are:
  parse(::Type{T}, ::AbstractString) where T<:Complex at parse.jl:381
  parse(::Type{Sockets.IPAddr}, ::AbstractString) at ~/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.8/Sockets/src/IPAddr.jl:246
  parse(::Type{T}, ::AbstractChar; base) where T<:Integer at parse.jl:40
  ...
Stacktrace:
 [1] iterate
   @ ./generator.jl:47 [inlined]
 [2] _collect
   @ ./array.jl:807 [inlined]
 [3] collect_similar
   @ ./array.jl:716 [inlined]
 [4] map
   @ ./abstractarray.jl:2933 [inlined]
 [5] top-level scope
   @ ~/proc/self/fd/0:1
in expression starting at /proc/self/fd/0:1
exit status 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Easy peasy like this:

   ```
   function str2vec(s::String)
       return map(x->parse(Int,x), split(s,""))
   end
   ```

   ```
   julia> str2vec("124")
   3-element Vector{Int64}:
    1
    2
    4
   ```
2. Or by broadcasting:

   ```
   julia> parse.(Int, split("124",""))
   3-element Vector{Int64}:
    1
    2
    4
   ```
3. By piping functions:

   ```
   julia> "124" |> x->split(x, "") |> x->parse.(Int, x)
   3-element Vector{Int64}:
    1
    2
    4
   ```
4. Utilizing the `eachsplit` function, which is a lazy function and returns a generator object (introduced in Julia 1.8):

   ```
   julia> eachsplit("124", "") |> x->parse.(Int, x)
   3-element Vector{Int64}:
    1
    2
    4
   ```
5. According to [Dan's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74459107/how-to-convert-string-to-array-with-no-spaces/74459520?noredirect=1#comment131448405_74459520), you try another ways:

   - Using the `Int8` on the collected `char`s:

   ```
   julia> Int8.(collect("124")).-48
   3-element Vector{Int64}:
    1
    2
    4
   ```

   - Using the `Iterators.map`:

   ```
   julia> collect(Iterators.map(x->Int8(x)-48,"124"))
   3-element Vector{Int64}:
    1
    2
    4
   ```
6. Also, one can consider the [DNF's proposal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74459107/how-to-convert-string-to-array-with-no-spaces/74459520?noredirect=1#comment131448405_74459520):

   ```
   julia> [Int(x)-48 for x in "124"]
   3-element Vector{Int64}:
    1
    2
    4
   ```

---

## Benchmarking

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> @btime str2vec("124");
       @btime parse.(Int, split("124",""));
       @btime "124" |> x->split(x, "") |> x->parse.(Int, x);
       @btime eachsplit("124", "") |> x->parse.(Int, x);
       @btime Int8.(collect("124")).-48;
       @btime collect(Iterators.map(x->Int8(x)-48,"123"));
       @btime [Int(x)-48 for x in "123"]
  681.250 ns (11 allocations: 864 bytes)
  675.460 ns (11 allocations: 864 bytes)
  679.747 ns (11 allocations: 864 bytes)
  1.280 μs (14 allocations: 816 bytes)
  92.412 ns (2 allocations: 160 bytes)
  61.711 ns (1 allocation: 80 bytes)
  45.152 ns (1 allocation: 80 bytes)
```

Comment: `Int8.(collect("124")).-48` gets the result and is 5x faster than `parse.(Int, split("124",""))` and other options. Note, this is good for digits only string. `collect(Iterators.map(x->Int8(x)-48,"123"))` even faster (less allocation)

Comment: @DNF, You're right . Thanks for mentioning it! I'll add it as well. I guess *Dan* considered the `Int8` since the numbers in the example are small.

Comment: @Shayan, I deleted the comment you just replied to and turned it into an answer, since it also was relevant for the 'safe' version, sorry about that. In total I decided it was worth its own answer. You should still use it in your answer, since that is aiming to be the comprehensive one.

Comment: @DNF, No there isn't anything to be sorry about! It's okay and I saw it and cast a vote ♥.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the inbuilt `digits` function.

By default, it returns the digits last-to-first:

```
julia> digits(parse(Int, "1234"))
4-element Vector{Int64}:
 4
 3
 2
 1
```

You can `reverse!` the result if you want them in the same order as in the string:

```
julia> digits(parse(Int, "1234")) |> reverse!
4-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
 3
 4
```

This runs much faster than `parse`ing each digit individually. The  `Int8(...) .- 48` method is still faster, but it fails silently if the input string happens to be invalid, which could be dangerous further down the line. Since we're using `parse` here, this method reports the error correctly in such cases.

```
julia> Int8.(collect("invalid")).-48
7-element Vector{Int64}:
 57
 62
 70
 49
 60
 57
 52

julia> digits(parse(Int, "invalid")) |> reverse!
ERROR: ArgumentError: invalid base 10 digit 'i' in "invalid"
```

Answer (score 1):

Both other answers are very good, but they have forgotten about comprehensions. Using a comprehension gives both the fastest *safe* solution, and the absolute fastest solution, tied with the `Iterators.map`.

Fastest *unsafe* (based on the answer by @Shayan with input from @DanGetz):

```
julia> @btime [Int(c)-48 for c in "123"]
  34.372 ns (1 allocation: 80 bytes)
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
 3
```

The above will silently return the wrong answer for invalid inputs, as noted by @SundarR.

Here's an even nicer and more intuitive version of the above, which is the same under the hood:

```
[c - '0' for c in "123"]
```

It works because `Int('0')` equals 48, and subtraction of `Char`s yields an `Int`.

Fastest *safe* solution (based on @SundarR's answer):

```
julia> @btime [parse(Int, c) for c in "123"]
  47.822 ns (1 allocation: 80 bytes)
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> [parse(Int, c) for c in "invalid"]
ERROR: ArgumentError: invalid base 10 digit 'i'
```

I would probably recommend the latter in most cases.

One more thing you may or may not be aware of: You can create a generator instead of a vector, in case you don't actually need the vector itself, but want to iterate over the converted numbers for some other purpose. The syntax is almost identical to an array comprehension, just use `()` instead:

```
g = (parse(Int, c) for c in "123")
for val in g
    println(val, " squared equals ", val^2)
end
1 squared equals 1
2 squared equals 4
3 squared equals 9
```

This will not allocate an intermediate temporary vector, and creating the generator is essentially free:

```
julia> @btime (parse(Int, c) for c in "123")
  1.900 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
```

The computational cost is paid during iteration instead. This is similar to using `Iterators.map` without `collect`, but arguably has nicer syntax.